# Disable Cloudflare error pages and show the actual error page

Tags: cloudflare

I want to know what the actual error is. I was able to hide it temporary, and it gave me a database connection error, so I tweaked the username and password. Now it's back to an error page.

How do I disable this error page entirely? I tried development mode, but it is still showing the actual error.

[image]

Besides, the error isn't entirely true:

```
# systemctl status nginx
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-03-28 20:44:47 UTC; 11min ago
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app errors will continue to show when possible. However the error above is 521, meaning cloudflare could not even reach your server for any sort of reply.

More on that here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171916-Error-521-Web-server-is-down

Answer (score 0):

Users on the Enterprise plan may be able to accomplish something like that.  However, you should be able use your own error logs to get that type of information.